# Vue-Router4/TypeScript "No overload matches this call"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to caoncatinate multiple vue-router 4 file.ts to the main vue-router(index.ts) using typescript, but it gives the error "***TS2769: No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray[]): never[]', gave the following error. Argument of type 'RouteRecordRaw[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray'.
The types returned by 'slice(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'RouteRecordRaw[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'....***"

Here is my files.

**DashboardRouter.ts**

```
import { RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";
const DashboardRouter: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
{
  path: "/",
  redirect: "/dashboard",
  component: () => import("@/layout/Layout.vue"),
  children: [
    {
      path: "/dashboard",
      name: "dashboard",
      component: () => import("@/views/Dashboard.vue"),
     },
   ]
  },
];
export default DashboardRouter;
```

**GuestRouter.ts**

```
import { RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";
const GuestRouter: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: () => import("@/views/auth/Login.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/password-reset",
    name: "password-reset",
    component: () => import("@/views/auth/PasswordReset.vue")
  },
  {
   // the 404 route, when none of the above matches
    path: "/404",
    name: "error-404",
    component: () => import("@/views/error/Error404.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
    redirect: "/404"
  }
];
export default GuestRouter;
```

**Index.ts**(Main Router)

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";
import store from "@/store";
import { Mutations, Actions } from "@/store/enums/StoreEnums";
import DashboardRoute from "./DashboardRouter";
import GuestRoute from "./GuestRouter";

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [].concat(GuestRoute, DashboardRoute);

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
});

router.beforeEach(() => {
  // reset config to initial state
  store.commit(Mutations.RESET_LAYOUT_CONFIG);

  // Scroll page to top on every route change
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, 100);
});    
export default router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `[]` is not typed.

One way to fix this is to use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) on the `[]`:

```js
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = ([] as Array<RouteRecordRaw>).concat(GuestRoute, DashboardRoute);

// or
const routes = ([] as Array<RouteRecordRaw>).concat(GuestRoute, DashboardRoute);

// or
const routes = ([] as RouteRecordRaw[]).concat(GuestRoute, DashboardRoute);
```

A more succinct way is to [spread the arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#a_better_way_to_concatenate_arrays):

```js
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [...GuestRoute, ...DashboardRoute];

// or
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [...GuestRoute, ...DashboardRoute];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split out the RouteRecordRaw and import it as a type, which is what it is:

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import type { RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";
```

I had the same problem, just fixed it a few minutes ago.